# Hide dimension based on login

Tags: business-objects

I have a BO 4.1 environment that has been build by my predecessor (who is unreachable).

There are 2 universes.

Both are based on the same sourcetable.

Both contain the same clientdata (name, adress SSN).

I have two usergroups: TESTUSERS (standard-user) and POWERUSERS (admin).

When making a report through Webi, the users in the group TESTUSERS can see the SSN in Universe A but cannot see the SSN in Universe B.

TESTUSERS should not be able to see the SSN in Universe A.

POWERUSERS are allowed to see that data.

For the love of Stack Overflow I cannot find out how to the SSN is hidden in universe B (how it should be). How do I hide/show dimensions based on the group the login belongs to?

To be clear: the SSN should not be selectable for group TESTUSERS when creating/modifying a report. This question is not about how to hide the SSN in reports.

Comment: Is this a .unv universe or .unx?

Comment: All universes are  .unx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unx universes, objects can be hidden from certain user groups via **Business Security Profiles**.  In IDT, go to Window -> Security Editor, and log in to the session that the universe is in.  In the "Universes / Profiles" dialog, navigate to the universe that currently has the restriction applied.  Underneath that universe should be at least one security profile.  From here, you can edit it or view/change the groups it applies to.  To add the same restriction to the other universe, select that other universe and then click the "Insert Business Security Profile" icon above the universe list.